# Spring @value to inject values without properties file

Tags: spring

My question is simple. Consider the class below. I need to place value of i=1 , str ="abc" directly without using any properties file using @Value annotation. How to do that ?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Example {

    int i;
    String str;

    @Autowired
    AccountService obj;

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public void setObj(AccountService obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply do

```
@Component
public class Example {
    @Value("1")
    int i;
    @Value("abc")
    String str;

    @Autowired
    AccountService obj;

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public void setObj(AccountService obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

}
```

This is equivalent of writing in XML `<property name="" value="" />` which calls setter for injecting the values.

Comment: Great, I did not know that. I would delete my answer. +1